# jmeter running more tests than in CSV list

Tags: jmeter

I'm setup a jmeter test where I've added a `CSV Data set Config` with a list of IDs that I want the test to go through. The csv file has 10,000 IDs but when its running, it seems to run more than 10,000 tests.

I've set some of these setting as well:

```
Thread Group
Number of threads: 10
Ramp-up period: 1
Loop count: 1

CSV Data Set Config
Recycle on EOF: False
Stop thread of EOF: False
Sharing Mode: All threads
```

I then run the test via the cli like this:
`./jmeter.sh -f -n -t /home/user/rtf-load-csv-list.jmx -l /home/user/logtest/test.log -e -o /home/userhtml/`

when I do a `wc -l /home/user/logtest/test.log`, I see more than the 10,000 requests but there are only 10,000 IDs in the csv file.

why doesn't it stop after the initial 10,000?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Stop thread of EOF` to `True` otherwise when all 10000 values will be used JMeter will continue sending the requests with [default placeholder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#csv_dataset) of `<EOF>`

[image]

More information: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)